# Attempt to index nil with Instance

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I'm trying to make a combat system with a dictionary but there's this one error that stops the whole entire system. This is the script

```
local Dictionary = require(script.Dictionary)
 
local DictionaryHandler = {}

function DictionaryHandler.find(player, action)
    return Dictionary[action][player]
end

function DictionaryHandler.add(player, action)
    if not Dictionary[action][player] then
        Dictionary[action][player] = true
    end
end

function DictionaryHandler.remove(player, action)
    if Dictionary[action][player] then
        Dictionary[action][player] = nil
    end
end

return DictionaryHandler
```

The error says it in the title so yeah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to make a system for checking whether there is an action mapped to each player. But the problem comes from the initial check whether the key exists in the nested tables.

```
if not Dictionary[action][player] then
```

Reading the code from left to right, `Dictionary[action]` likely doesn't exist, so that evaluates to `nil`, and then you try to index `nil[player]` and it throws the error. And each of your functions have this issue.

So you need to double check that `Dictionary[action]` exists first, or you need to ensure that it always resolves to an empty table.

```
function DictionaryHandler.find(player, action)
    if not Dictionary[action] then
        return nil
    end
    return Dictionary[action][player]
end

function DictionaryHandler.add(player, action)
    if not Dictionary[action] then
        Dictionary[action] = {}
    end
    if not Dictionary[action][player] then
        Dictionary[action][player] = true
    end
end

function DictionaryHandler.remove(player, action)
    if Dictionary[action] then
        if Dictionary[action][player] then
            Dictionary[action][player] = nil
        end
        if next(Dictionary[action]) == nil then
            Dictionary[action] = nil
        end
    end
end
```